# Split & Transpose Array

Tags: google-sheets

I'm really struggling with a little formula I need to extract some data. Basically I have some data in a column like :

```
A+B  
A  
C+D|E
```

I want to extract everything unique before the | if it exists but also split any data that  has a +. So the result column would be :

```
A  
B  
C  
D
```

So far I have this :

```
unique(TRANSPOSE(split(query(LEFT(D3, FIND("|", D3&"|")-1), "SELECT Col1"),"+")))
```

which works for a single cell but I can't translate it to an array.

How could I do that, and is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  INDEX to get the first part of splitted array and then use the typical join/ split combo:

```
=UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("+",INDEX(SPLIT(D1:D3,"|"),,1)),"+")))
```

Comment: That got it. I'll work my way back through it to try and understand whats going on.Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: Make sure to mark the answer as correct if it works for you.